# Closing a view displayed via a modal segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I'm manually invoking a segue (set as modal) in order to display a login form in Xcode 4.2 using Storyboards with the following line of code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:nil];
```

I'm probably missing something really simple, however I can't find a way to programmatically close the login view and return to the previous view.

The view is part of a navigation view controller, so setting the segue type to "push" allows me to use the back button to send me back to my previous screen, but in "modal" mode, I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this (after button press, for example)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: xcode is an IDE only, ill edit this

Answer (score 173, accepted):

If your deployment target is iOS 5.0 or later, use this message:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or in Swift:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

If your deployment target is older, use this (deprecated) message:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I tried this already and it doesn't appear to do anything. Does this have any special conditions?

Comment: I made a trivial test case with two VCs in a storyboard.  The initial VC has a "Modal" button with a modal segue to the second VC.  The second VC has a "Dismiss" button wired to a method that does `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.  It works as expected.  I don't know of any special conditions.

Comment: I just want to point out that I have resolved this issue. Being new to storyboards, I didn't set my segue type to modal one one instance so it was a user error! Thanks.

Comment: I also try this one:    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] and it also works , why?

Comment: The presenting view controller does the dismissing.  When you send it to the presented view controller, the presented view controller forwards the message to the presenting view controller automatically.

Comment: Use NULL for completion handler. `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];`

Answer (score 13):

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` is a new way in IOS5

Answer (score 5):

The following should work fine...

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I do exactly this with a login page in my [latest tutorial here](http://maybelost.com/2011/12/tutorial-storyboard-app-with-core-data/), with no issues.

Comment: Now deprecated in iOS7:
Use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: instead.

Answer (score 4):

The following code works in swift 3:

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```